# Reset Turtlebot odometry in a Python script

Tags: navigation, odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using `rostopic pub /mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry std_msgs/Empty` to reset odometry on Turtlebot. It works fine but I want to do the same thing in a Python script. Here is my code:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Empty

rospy.init_node('reset_odom')

pub = rospy.Publisher('/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry', Empty, queue_size=10)
pub.publish(Empty())
```

It doesn't work. Could you point out what is wrong with it?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203088/reset-turtlebot-odometry-in-a-python-script/) by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-02-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AbdRenawi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28149/abdrenawi/) on 2016-10-04**:
I have the same issue, did you get any response ??

**Comment by [haelannaleah](https://answers.ros.org/users/29013/haelannaleah/) on 2017-02-10**:
In my initial explorations, if that command goes in the main control loop, it seems to work, but if it's only published a couple times, it fails to reset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For whatever reason, it looks publishing information to the reset topic takes a bit of time to get through.
I'm using the reset command in the initialization of a navigation class, so I was able to get away with a quarter second busy loop for it:

```
import rospy

from std_msgs.msg import Empty
from time import time

# set up node
rospy.init_node('reset_odom')

# set up the odometry reset publisher
reset_odom = rospy.Publisher('/mobile_base/commands/reset_odometry', Empty, queue_size=10)
    
# reset odometry (these messages take a few iterations to get through)
timer = time()
while time() - timer < 0.25:
    reset_odom.publish(Empty())
```

It probably makes sense to reset odom as part of an initialization step, in which case, a busy loop shouldn't affect normal robot function. However, if you want to be able to do this on the fly, you're probably going to want to come up with a non-blocking way to loop the command.

---

Originally posted by [haelannaleah](https://answers.ros.org/users/29013/haelannaleah/) with karma: 28 on 2017-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1